# captcha supports accessibility

Tags: java, wicket

I am implementing a captcha in my application, where I had an old one does not support [accessibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility/What_is_accessibility).

I have searched a lot, so I found google reCAPTCHA, but this has privacy concerning since the application is working in EU, and google reCAPTCHA is not friendly with GDPR and personal data will be collected by google.

Furthermore, I found another reCAPTCHA called mtcaptcha [www.mtcaptcha.com](http://www.mtcaptcha.com), but it is expensive.

My application UI is built on wicket, so it is Java as front and backend.

Anyone has an idea how I can overcome the two challenges:

1- EU GDPR

2- support [accessibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility/What_is_accessibility)

I have right now captcha something like this which is not support accessibility :

### [old captcha demo](https://examples8x.wicket.apache.org/captcha/;jsessionid=A8E76C7CF014998AD0FF17CCE9FDAEC3?0)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic on SO (asking for tool/framework recomendations). Please see [ask] and [help].

Comment: I improved the question , do you think it is still out of topic?